# Visited link color changes

Tags: php, html, css

I have this class:

```
.news_item_info 
{
    font-size: .7em; 
    color:#000000; 
    text-indent: 30px;
    a:link { color: #000000; }
    a:visited { color: #000000; }   
}
```

Here its with code:

```
<div class="news_item_info">
    <?php echo $articles[$index]->getPoints(); ?> puntos por <span class="news_item_user"><a href="/index.php?action=user&param=<?php echo $articles[$index]->getUsername(); ?>">
    <?php echo $articles[$index]->getUsername(); ?></a> </span>
    <?php echo $articles[$index]->getElapsedDateTime(); ?> | <span class="comments_count"><a href="<?php echo "/index.php?action=comments&param=".$articles[$index]->getId(); ?>"><?php echo $articles[$index]->getNumberOfComments($articles[$index]->getId()); ?> comentarios</a></span>
</div>
```

The problem is that after I visit the user profile it shows as gray and I want to keep the black color.

If anyone knows the answer I will appreciate it.

Comment: Even though you can't do that with CSS, it'd be pretty cool if you could.

Comment: @Paolo: you can do that with CSS, except the syntax is different.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The CSS posted is invalid, you have to qualify the styles by cascading definition.  Try un-nesting your link definitions like so:

```
.news_item_info 
{
    font-size: .7em; 
    color:#000000; 
    text-indent: 30px;       
}

.news_item_info a:link { color: #000000; }
.news_item_info a:visited { color: #000000; }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't do CSS like that (nested blocks).

```
.news_item_info 
{
    font-size: .7em; 
    color:#000000; 
    text-indent: 30px;
}

.news_item_info a:link { color: #000000; }
.news_item_info a:visited { color: #000000; }
```